# What's the safest earlier age a foal can be vaccinated against tetanus and strangles?

Tags: horses, vaccination

If the foal misses out on the mother's colostrum, they may miss out on immunity from the mother. In this case the foal didn't get colostrum and her IGG tests were poor. She had two plasma infusions to help her immune system. The vet wanted her to have her vaccinations earlier.

What's the safest  earlier age a foal can be vaccinated against tetanus and strangles?

Can one be given more safely earlier than the other?

*note: I will go with the vet's instructions, I find it an interesting question to understand the why*

Answer (score 2):

Where I live, the first vaccine is given when the foal is 5-7 months old and it is given twice. The second vaccine is given 4-6 weeks after the first one.

If the mare is unvaccinated, the tetanus vaccine can be given when the foal is 3 months old.

After this, the tetanus vaccine is given every 3 years and the flue vaccine is given every year.

This is how it is here in Norway, but it can be different where you live; the types of vaccines given might differ, too - but a vet will tell you more about this.

Comment: Yep. I will speak to the vet, she wanted to foal to have the shots sooner

Comment: one of the problems is the mothers milk can contain antibodies against the illnesses you vaccsinate the foal against and this might make the vaccsine less effective i think.

Comment: in this case the foal didn't get the mother's antibodies.

Comment: ok this changes things a little.